# Stop getting traffic from Googlebot on high server load

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-crawlers, googlebot, robots.txt

In my website, we usually get a spike in the number of requests because of search engine crawlers (like Googlebot) harvesting the website for indexing.

So what I thought of; is depending on the server health (CPU Utilization), by which I can respond with 503 to the bots if the server is on heavy load, so they stop crawling and come back again after some time which I will specify in the "Retry-After" header.

**My questions are:**

1. Will responding with 503 for any Robots.txt request stop the Googlebot (to be specific) from accessing all of my website resources?
2. Do I need to respond with 503 for all of my website resources, and if I did that, will it stop Googlebot from retrying, and will it obey the "Retry-After" header

Comment: See [Official Google Webmaster Central Blog: How to deal with planned site downtime](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2011/01/how-to-deal-with-planned-site-downtime.html) which talks a bit about Googlebot, 503 response, and the retry-after header.

Comment: See [Googlebot 503 Retry-After - Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/1Hk5538XxIc/iLssQOhfiykJ) where somebody asks about Googlebot and retry-after.